# PC powers off when running heavy stuff

Tags: linux, laptop, hardware-failure, power

I've a "new" laptop (Sony Vaio VGN-NS130FE, from 2008) which I installed Parabola GNU/Linux-libre (Based on Arch Linux) and for some reason, when running heavy stuff it powers off. For example, compiling packages while running the web browser, or moving/copying 10GB+ of data from one HDD to other. And those are not that heavy, but for this laptop yes. It starts to do a lot of noise (the fan) an then shuts down, but it's like if I do it manually, so it smells like it's sth. of software more than hardware. Unless there's a hardware issue where the OS says "ok, the PC **must** power off, or it'll die", but in the case it's not like that, ¿what could be the problem?

NOTE: I haven't tried other OSes

Comment: What are your temperatures?

Comment: Open it up, clean dust out of fans, make sure that thermal pads are making solid contact. Replace thermal materials if necessary.